# Environment variables are undefined during Cloud Run Build

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-run

I use Google Cloud Run to containerize the node.js app. I added environment variables to the google cloud run by following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting) and expect to use them inside my application code. But. Whenever I run build (cloud run build) it shows me that `process.env.NODE_ENV` and other enviroenment variables are `undefined`.

Could you help me to find the root problem of the issue?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.16.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
RUN npx knex --knexfile=./src/infrastructure/knex/knex.config.ts migrate:latest --env production

# Use the official lightweight Node.js 14 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:14.16.0

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Install production dependencies.
# If you add a package-lock.json, speed your build by switching to 'npm ci'.
# RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile


COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8080

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "yarn", "prod" ]
```

This line of code throws error

```
RUN npx knex --knexfile=./src/infrastructure/knex/knex.config.ts migrate:latest --env production
```

This is `knex.config.ts`

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import { Knex } from 'knex'
import { envConfig, NodeEnvEnum } from '../../configs/env.config'

console.log('ASDASD', process.env.NODE_ENV, envConfig.environment, process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME, envConfig.databaseCloudSqlConnection)

export const knexConfig: Record<NodeEnvEnum, Knex.Config> = {
  [NodeEnvEnum.Development]: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: envConfig.databaseUrl,
    migrations: {
      extension: 'ts'
    }
  },
  [NodeEnvEnum.Production]: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: envConfig.databaseName,
      user: envConfig.databaseUser,
      password: envConfig.databasePassword,
      host: `/cloudsql/${envConfig.databaseCloudSqlConnection}`
    }
  }
}

export default knexConfig
```

This is `env.config.ts`

```js
export enum NodeEnvEnum {
  Production = 'production',
  Development = 'development'
}

interface EnvConfig {
  serverPort: string
  environment: NodeEnvEnum

  // Database
  databaseCloudSqlConnection: string
  databaseUrl: string
  databaseUser: string
  databasePassword: string
  databaseName: string
}

export const envConfig: EnvConfig = {
  serverPort: process.env.SERVER_PORT as string,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV as NodeEnvEnum,

  // Database
  databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL as string,
  databaseCloudSqlConnection: process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME as string,
  databaseName: process.env.DB_NAME as string,
  databaseUser: process.env.DB_USER as string,
  databasePassword: process.env.DB_PASSWORD as string
}
```

Example of the error from the Cloud Run logs

[image]
(logs are shown from bottom to top)

Comment: Where are you setting the env var NODE_ENV? can you describe how do you run the build? The command or the UI action to achieve that?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Environment variables like NODE_ENV are set via Cloud Run UI. See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting. The build is running automatically after pushing changes to the develop branch. Google Cloud Run listen to changes and triggers build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing context here.

There are 3 contexts that you need to be aware of.

1. The observer that launches the Cloud Build process based on Git push.
2. The Cloud Build job is triggered by the observer, and it's executed on a sandboxed environment, it's a build process. A step/command fails in this step, because for this context you have not defined the ENV variables.
   When the build is finished, it places the image to GCR repository.
3. Then "the image" is taken and used by Cloud Run as a service, here you define the ENV variables for the service itself, for your application code and not for your build process.

In Context 2, you need to end up using substitution variables read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values).

[image]

Comment: As far I understand my Cloud Build is not aware of ENV variables that I declared in Cloud Run? How should I run database schema migration inside continuous deployment then?

Comment: By following this article https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables it says: When you set environment variables, they are injected into the container and are accessible to your code. I thought that I can declare ENV variables there (in Cloud Run config via UI) and they will be accessible inside my code. Before starting the project I want to run database schema migration to ensure that Sql Schema is up-to-date.

Comment: Please read my answer. There are two things. Cloud Build and Cloud Run. Dockerfile is part of cloud build process. It has nothing to do with Cloud Run, which executes and injects the ENV variables to your application and not to your Build.

Comment: > Dockerfile is part of cloud build process. It has nothing to do with Cload Run, which executes and injects the ENV variables to your application and not to your Build. 

Clear

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi: Your env var defined are only for the runtime, not for the build time. If you want to add build time variable, you need to build your Cloudbuild.yaml file and to customize your build step. It's not a standard/ad-hoc build stetp that can generate automatically Cloud Run.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Understandable. I was thinking that ENV variables should be accessible within the build. I missed that Cloud Build is used before running Cloud Run. Thank you a lot. I will try to investigate your recommendations more precisely

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you should make a tutorial of this, it's interesting and you are the perfect guy for it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause turned out to be that my `.env` files weren't getting copied into the Docker container upon deployment. Fixed it by adding `.gcloudignore` and `.dockerignore` files in the root of the repository.

Comment: Hi jeremy can you pls elaborate? Thanks

Comment: What specifically do you need elaboration on?

Comment: @JeremyBernier what did you add to these ignore files?

Comment: @Bowis I added to both files:

node_modules
.next

But should work even if the files are empty