# Next.js on Cloud Run - how to get environment variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js

How to get access to env vars in Next.js running on Cloud Run. I explicitly need to set variables through Clour Run config (as our team is using it for other services), but  Next.js does not seem to pick those up in runtime.

I saw this answer [How to Access ENV Variables in Google Cloud Run using Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972329/how-to-access-env-variables-in-google-cloud-run-using-next-js) but it seem to be focusing more on getting variables into the browser.

Comment: Have you checked this similar [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67327008/18265570)?

Comment: A mod deleted my answer telling me to flag this question as a duplicate without doing so himself (I guess he thinks he's doing the public a service by deleting real answers in empty Q&A threads?). Anyways check my solution in this thread, just need to add .gcloudignore and .dockerignore files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893360/environment-variables-are-undefined-during-cloud-run-build/75300755?noredirect=1#comment134133579_75300755

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variables are undefined during Cloud Run Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893360/environment-variables-are-undefined-during-cloud-run-build)